# Vim/FuzzyFinder freezes when doing :FufCoverageFile

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

While working on (presumably) any file in [this project](https://github.com/sitecrafting/conifer) in Vim, when I type `:FufCoverageFile`, Vim freezes and I have to completely exit the terminal window.

I thought it might be a cross-project issue with my .vimrc, but I've only ever seen it happen on this project. (Granted it probably still is a global issue with my config, just more subtle.)

I thought it might be an issue with vim sessions, but it happens whether or not I'm using a session. Plus, I deleted the project-specific session from ~/.vim/session and the issue persisted.

I considered (but didn't really believe) that it might be an issue with tmux, but it happens whether or not I'm inside a tmux session.

Just what in the heck. :)

[Here is my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/acobster/dotfiles/blob/44ee2e40e5e3c0c986614a9ac840272ccb9953e3/.vimrc) at tme of posting, for reference. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl I might just, if I can figure out where that is. The one on Bitbucket 404s and the one on GitHub redirects to pull requests. :P

Comment: This simply means that the project is abandoned. The code at vim.org and Github has not been updated since 2010. Time to drop the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @phd. I ended up switching to junegunn/fzf.vim.